# Get CodingBat problems to run in IDE

Tags: java

I'm new to programming so this is probably a very simple question, but I'm bashing my head against the wall.

I'm trying to get [this coding bat solution](http://codingbat.com/prob/p187868)  to run in my IDE, so i can play around and perform some modifications.

This is the solution displayed in coding bat. It's obviously incomplete for a java program.

```
public boolean sleepIn(boolean weekday, boolean vacation) {
  if (!weekday || vacation) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

This is what I'm trying to run in NetBeans

```
class CodingBat{
  public static void main(String[] args){
     public boolean sleepIn(boolean weekday, boolean vacation) {
  if (!weekday || vacation) {
  return true;
}
return false;
         }
      }
}
```

It tells me "public boolean.." is an illegal start of an expression.

It tells me the IF statement is redundant, but there's only one if..

it tells me the final bracket is unexpected.

Comment: You're putting the `sleepIn` method inside of the `main` method. You can't put methods inside other methods in `Java`. My suggestion would be to back up and start with a Java tutorial, not a codingBat tutorial. Basics like this are required before writing solutions to problems.

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this

```
class CodingBat{
  public static void main(String[] args){
      sleepIn(true, true);
  }
  public static boolean sleepIn(boolean weekday, boolean vacation) {
      if (!weekday || vacation) {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
}
```

In Java, you are not able to declare a method from within another method. You instead need to create method outside the main method, but within the class and then call it, passing in whatever parameters you need